# Figure out what is printed to the console

Tags: java

What will be the output of the following code ?

```
String[] letters =
        { "laid", "leave", "lean", "ease", "east", "legals", "revo", "fights", "limit", "live" };
int result = Stream.of( letters )
        .filter( w -> isVowel( w.charAt( 3 ) ) )
        .mapToInt( w -> w.length() )
        .filter( w -> w % 2 == 0 )
        .sum();
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Did you try to run it?

Comment: Depends on what `isVowel` does, you didn't include that.

Comment: 18=4+6+4+4. ease, legals, revo and live has vowel at index 3 and even length. note that we exclude 'limit' because length is odd.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to find out the result without running the code:

```
int result = Stream.of(letters)
.filter(w -> isVowel(w.charAt(3))) // I'm assuming isVowel returns true for vowels (a,e,i,o,u),
                                   // so after this step only the Strings whose 4th character 
                                   // (index 3) is a vowel (such as "ease") remain in the 
                                   // Stream
.mapToInt(w -> w.length()) // here you transform each remaining String to its length
                           // (for example "ease" becomes 4)
.filter(w -> w % 2 == 0) // here you keep only the even lengths
.sum(); // finally you sum the remaining lengths
```

This should be easy enough to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

**NB** I'm assuming isVowel returns true if the argument is a vowel.

After executing filter(), you will end up with a list of all strings whose 4th character is a vowel.

Which means after the filter is applied you'll now have a list of

["ease", "legal", "revo", "limit", "live"]

Now your next instruction (mapToInt) says convert this list of strings to a list of integers. And how do you determine what these integers will be? Their length. The next instructions is saying creating me a list of all the lengths of the remaining strings after filtering. Which means you'll end up with a list of

[4, 5, 4, 5, 4]

Now the next operation says can you give me a list of numbers that when divided by 2 the remainder is 0? This is a list of even numbers. So the next result will be

[4, 4, 4]

Now the last instruction says, can you sum up the contents of the last evaluated list?

this is 4*3 = 12.